# Evaluate integral of $z/(z^2 + 2z + 5)\,dz$ around the unit circle

Tags: calculus

Evaluate integral

$$\int_c\frac{z}{(z^2 + 2z + 5)}\,dz,$$
where $c$ is the unit circle

I take $u = z^2 +2z$, then $du = 2z+2$, but that not work

Comment: This follows by an application of residue theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem . Cauchy's integral theorem also works...

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure that the answer is zero. By the residue theorem ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)), we need to find out how many poles the closed curve (unit circle) winds around. Looking for points where the function is undefined, solve $z^2 + 2z + 5 = 0$ by completing the square; this gives $z = -1 + 2i, -1 - 2i$ and both of these points are clearly outside the unit circle (height $±2i$ in the complex plane). So the curve winds around no poles and it follows that the integral must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $z=e^{i\varphi}, \ \varphi\in [0,2\pi\rangle$, and in the very next step take $t=e^{i\varphi}$. Then you have
$$
\frac{1}{i} \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \! \frac{e^{2i\varphi}}{e^{2i\varphi}+2e^{i\varphi}+5} \, \mathrm{d}\varphi = - \int\limits_1^{1} \! \frac{t}{t^2+2t+5} \, \mathrm{d}t=0.
$$

It's 3 AM so I'm really sorry if I made a mistake. But even if I did make an arithmetic mistake somewhere in my steps, what I've shown would be a good way to go if you want to avoid the Residue theorem or Cauchy's integral formula.

Also, you should check first to see if the roots of the quadratic equation $z^2+2z+5=0$ lie on the unit circle or not, then do this.

Answer (score -1):

my answer for the question above 
[image]

Comment: This is not correct, a fast reason, what happened with the unit circle? This is definite integral on the complex plane (I suppose that for the unit circle around we are integrating) This gives a number.